# My mern app fails to run on heroku. How can I fix this error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, mern

I followed [Brad Traversys Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71wSzpLyW9k&t=95s) to build this basic MERN Stack App using React.js, Redux.js, Node.js, Express.js, and MongoDB with create-react-app and Mlab. The App works fine on my local server with no errors, however I am having trouble deploying it to Heroku.

I  deployed the app using the Heroku CLI, and got the message:

```
     deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/salty-temple-63286.git
   d4eeb21..473c3c0  master -> master
```

However When I [visit my app](https://salty-temple-63286.herokuapp.com/) I get the following error message:

> Application error An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs
>   for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
>   heroku logs --tail

Here is the logs:

```
$ heroku logs --tail
2019-01-04T04:03:49.583742+00:00 app[web.1]: at require
(internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-01-04T04:03:49.583743+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/api/items.js:5:14)
2019-01-04T04:03:49.583745+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
2019-01-04T04:03:49.583746+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
2019-01-04T04:03:49.583748+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
2019-01-04T04:03:49.583749+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
2019-01-04T04:03:49.583751+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
2019-01-04T04:03:49.583752+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-01-04T04:03:49.583753+00:00 app[web.1]: at require
(internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-01-04T04:03:49.583755+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:5:15)
2019-01-04T04:03:49.583756+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
2019-01-04T04:03:49.583758+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
2019-01-04T04:03:49.583759+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
2019-01-04T04:03:49.595916+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-01-04T04:03:49.596791+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-01-04T04:03:49.598998+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mern-todo-list@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2019-01-04T04:03:49.599272+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-01-04T04:03:49.599660+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-01-04T04:03:49.599892+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mern-todo-list@1.0.0 start script.
2019-01-04T04:03:49.600155+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-01-04T04:03:49.606443+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-04T04:03:49.606744+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A
complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-01-04T04:03:49.606972+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
  /app/.npm/_logs/2019-01-04T04_03_49_602Z-debug.log
2019-01-04T04:03:49.702411+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-01-04T04:03:49.684411+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process
exited with status 1
2019-01-04T04:31:16.938787+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=salty-temple-63286.herokuapp.com request_id=f0b7eaee-06e7-4967-a074-59aa0e9a8049 fwd="70.178.46.128" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-01-04T04:31:17.235532+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=salty-temple-63286.herokuapp.com request_id=9b2a211f-3884-4d98-893f-6564e6acd763 fwd="70.178.46.128" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-01-04T04:49:22.138341+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-01-04T04:49:33.868352+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661765+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661802+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661805+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661806+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661808+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../../models/Item'
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661810+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661812+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661814+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661816+00:00 app[web.1]: at require
(internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661817+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/api/items.js:5:14)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661819+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661821+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661822+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661824+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661826+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661827+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661829+00:00 app[web.1]: at require
(internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661830+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:5:15)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661832+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661834+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.661836+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
2019-01-04T04:49:36.671225+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-01-04T04:49:36.671934+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-01-04T04:49:36.675221+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mern-todo-list@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2019-01-04T04:49:36.675350+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-01-04T04:49:36.675658+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-01-04T04:49:36.675859+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mern-todo-list@1.0.0 start script.
2019-01-04T04:49:36.676063+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-01-04T04:49:36.683266+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-04T04:49:36.683410+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A
complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-01-04T04:49:36.683500+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
  /app/.npm/_logs/2019-01-04T04_49_36_677Z-debug.log
2019-01-04T04:49:36.746910+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process
exited with status 1
2019-01-04T05:08:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user tony@wheelertechconsulting.com
2019-01-04T05:09:53.657668+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 5dfee3cd by user tony@wheelertechconsulting.com
2019-01-04T05:10:07.043883+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-01-04T05:10:07.195622+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-01-04T05:10:23.550457+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715690+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715709+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715711+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715712+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715714+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../../models/Item'
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715717+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715719+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715721+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715723+00:00 app[web.1]: at require
(internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715725+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/api/items.js:5:14)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715726+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715728+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715729+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715731+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715732+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715734+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715735+00:00 app[web.1]: at require
(internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715737+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:5:15)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715738+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715740+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.715741+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
2019-01-04T05:10:29.729403+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-01-04T05:10:29.730408+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-01-04T05:10:29.733076+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mern-todo-list@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2019-01-04T05:10:29.733443+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-01-04T05:10:29.734184+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-01-04T05:10:29.734545+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mern-todo-list@1.0.0 start script.
2019-01-04T05:10:29.734884+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-01-04T05:10:29.776964+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-04T05:10:29.777279+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A
complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-01-04T05:10:29.777445+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
  /app/.npm/_logs/2019-01-04T05_10_29_737Z-debug.log
2019-01-04T05:10:29.867624+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-01-04T05:10:29.850311+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process
exited with status 1
2019-01-04T05:11:20.716383+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=salty-temple-63286.herokuapp.com request_id=6ec0a43b-6e8a-45a8-ae8c-f4ced564fec5 fwd="70.178.46.128" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here are some relevant excerpts from my files:
From server.js:

```
// Serve static assets if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

and

```
// DB config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;
```

My server side .gitignore

```
node_modules/
package-lock.json
config/keys_dev.js
```

My server side package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "mern-todo-list",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A todo list built with the mern stack",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm i --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "Tony Wheeler",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  }
}
```

My config/keys.js :

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  module.exports = require("./keys_prod");
} else {
  module.exports = require("./keys_dev");
}
```

My config/keys_prod.js

```
module.exports = {
  mongoURI: process.env.MONGO_URI
};
```

In my heroku dashboard I configured my config vars to:

> MONGO_URI
>   mongodb://myusername:mypassword@ds147344.mlab.com:47344/mern_todo

As I said My App works with my DB on my local server, but doesn't work on heroku.

Here is the full code on Github: https://github.com/twheelertech/mern-todo-list

I have successfully deployed MERN to heroku before, but haven't encountered this error before now.

Can anyone help me understand how to fix this?

Comment: `Error: Cannot find module '../../models/Item'` double check your casing? is the file called `item.js` not `Item.js`

Comment: yup.. https://github.com/twheelertech/mern-todo-list/blob/master/models/item.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: Cannot find module '../../models/Item'

You're probably developing on a mac which is lenient with import casings.

The file is called `item.js` and linux systems will not find `Item.js`. Make sure your casings match import statements. There's an eslint warning for this:

https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unresolved.md#casesensitive

Comment: Thank you Azium.  This was in fact the issue. Problem solved. :)  Btw:  I am on Windows 10 using Git Bash.